# retrofit call execute using rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

Scenario :

- Create request

  ```
  **Interface**

    @GET("someurl.mp4")
    @Streaming
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(); // retrofit2.Call


  **call**

  RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
   //okhttp3.ResponseBody
  Call<ResponseBody> request = retrofitInterface.downloadFile();
  try {
      downloadFile(request.execute().body());
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```
- Download bytes by bytes

  ```
  private void downloadFile(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {

  int count;
  byte[] data;
  data = new byte[1024 * 4];
  long fileSize = body.contentLength();
  Log.i("Download", "downloadFile: " + fileSize);
  InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
  File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
  try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
      long total = 0;
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Log.i("Download", "downloadFile size: " + fileSize);
      int timeCount = 1;
      while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {

          total += count;
          totalFileSize = (int) (fileSize / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));
          double current = Math.round(total / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));

          int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / fileSize);

          long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

          Download download = new Download();
          download.setTotalFileSize(totalFileSize);

          if (currentTime > 1000 * timeCount) {

              download.setCurrentFileSize((int) current);
              download.setProgress(progress);
              sendNotification(download);
              timeCount++;
          }
          if (download.getProgress() != 0)
              Log.i("Download", "progress: " + download.getProgress());

          output.write(data, 0, count);
      }
      onDownloadComplete();
      output.flush();
      //output.close();
  }
  bis.close();
  }
  ```

**Problem**

I am not able to port above code in `RxJava` using `Observable`/`Single` interface.
All i want is to download file bytes by bytes for some purpose.

I tried to call `downloadFile(request.execute().body());` inside ongoing async operation(RxJava) but didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason to declare method as returning *Call<ResponseBody>* if you are using RxJava anyway. Declare it as *Single<ResponseBody>* and use its result directly.

Comment: I don't want direct response object. I want to download file bytes by bytes. Single interface will return single body which contains file object.

Comment: Indeed, I missed your point. I have a vaguely similar example in RxSwift, perhaps you can get something out of it to use with RxJava - https://github.com/maxvol/RxOnDemandResources/blob/master/RxOnDemandResources/ODRFetcher.swift